# Dependency Injection for Classes within .Net Core Worker

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, serilog

I am trying to use Serilog in custom classes in a .Net core worker service and am seeing some strange issues. My setup is as follows:

Program.cs:

```
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("====================================================================");
            Log.Information($"Application Starts. Version: {System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Version}");
            Log.Information($"Application Directory: {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Fatal(e, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.Information("====================================================================");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
```

And:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                // configure the app here.
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .UseSerilog();
```

All pretty standard so far. I am then injecting the dependency into the Worker.cs as follows:

```
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

This works fine - I get log entries from the calls I make in here as expected. Where things fall down is when I create instances of my custom class. So, within my Worker.cs I do something like:

```
MyCustomProduct cProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomProduct>(response.Content);
```

So I am obviously taking a RestSharp response and deserializing it using MyCustomProduct class. All good. I am injecting the dependency into this class in the same way:

```
    private readonly ILogger<MyCustomProduct> _logger;

    public MyCustomProduct(ILogger<MyCustomProduct> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

However, when I try and make a call to _logger.LogInformation (or any other function obviously) from within this class, it fails, telling me that the reference to _logger is null.

I realise I am doing something fundamentally stupid here but I can't see it...

Comment: Why are you injecting a logger into a model class? That makes no sense. Also, how is it that `MyCustomProduct` can be deserialized when the constructor asks for a dependency that cannot be provided? Are you sure you don't have another empty constructor that is actually being used?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just want to be able to log out from within my class functions. Why can't the dependency be provided? There is definitely only a single constructor in the class.

Comment: My mistake - I thought that would throw an exception but for some reason it doesn't, and just passes `null` instead. It still has no way of getting that dependency from, the deserializer does not know or care about the DI container/framework

Comment: But this is outside the deserializer... that is only there to create instances of my product class